# Problem with Qjackctl

Tags: permissions, delete, nano

I am struggling with Qjackctl. One of the things that was suggested on a youtube video was to create a nano file and put in this code:

```
@audio  -  rtprio   -99                                            
@audio  -  memlock  -unlimited
@audio  -  nice     -19
```

However in my experimenting I have created more than one audio file and I believe that they are fighting each other. Ideally I would like to remove some of the files, but if I can't do this I would like to just make one of them blank.

How do I do this? Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: what problem did you faced with qjackctl? please mention the details

Comment: Ok, originally I discovered that it was the pulseaudio, and I learned this code: pulseaudio --kill enter jack_control  start. But jack control is very sensitive, and it doesn't seem to take much to have to start all over again. That is when I learned the above code, and now I am learning again. The last thing I did before I discovered that it wasn't working again was attempt to install absynth 5 using wine. Could that be the problem? It just says D-Bus JACK server Unable to connect to server. That is the same message that I have received in the past.

Comment: It looks like I typed some of this wrong. In the code I just mentioned it is jack_control  start.

Comment: Right underneath the connection graph change it says this: sh: 1: artshell:not found. I don't think that I have seen that error message before.

Comment: It may be a simple problem. I noticed that somehow aconnectgui was uninstalled. How do you link that interface with qjackctl for a midi connection?

Comment: Ok it was an interface issue. Still having just a little trouble saving the settings from Aconnectgui to Qjackctl. If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working. It was a simple issue. I just had to open zynaddsubfx before starting Qjackctl. In the above post, I had to change directories by doing this cd /etc/security. Then, I had to open the file limits.conf. That is where I put in the code:
@audio -  rtprio     -99
@audio -  memlock    unlimited
@audio -  nice       -19

After this, I saved the file.

These settings are at the very bottom of the page. After doing this and reinstalling aconnectgui I was successful.